# Laravel Отношение: один ко многим на примере двух таблиц

Tags: laravel

Как на примере двух таблиц: `table1`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и `table2`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

модифицировать запрос:

```
$data = $this->db->table('table1')->select('name', 'number', 'date', 'txt')->where('imei', '5812375612387218747')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
```

и модель `table1`:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class table1 extends Model
{
protected $table = 'table1';
protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'imei',
        'rid',
        'date',
        'type',
        'number',
        'name',
        'txt',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function filenames()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Table2');
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить не только 4 значения: `'name', 'number', 'date', 'txt'`, но и `filename` из `table2`, учитывая связывающие их поле `rid` ?

Comment: как минимум у вас связь hasMany должна быть со второй моделью Table2 а не Table1 во вторых зачем получать только часть свойств модели и нарушать ее целостность но это не принципиально

Comment: Т.е. предлагаете не использовать $fillable ? На самом деле проблема в связи этих 2х таблиц. Не совсем пойму что должно быть в моделе table1 и table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модель 1

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Table1 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table1';
    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'imei',
        'rid',
        'date',
        'type',
        'number',
        'name',
        'txt',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function filenames()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Table2::class,'rid','rid');
    }
}
```

Модель 2

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Table2 extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table1';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Table1::class,'rid','rid');
    }
}
```

В контроллере

```
$data = Table1::where('imei', '5812375612387218747')->with('filenames')->get();
dd($data);
```

Comment: Разобрался. При много благодарен!

Comment: В данном примере, из table2 подгружаются не только поле filename но и все остальные. А реально ли сделать select только поля filename?