# Laravel Запрос значений из связанной таблицы

Tags: php, laravel

Контроллер:

```
$data= table1::where('id', $id)
            ->with('listfile')
            ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
```

Модель table1:

```
namespace App\Models;
    protected $table = 'table1';
          public function listfile()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(table2::class,'rid','rid');
        }
```

Модель table2:

```
protected $table = 'table2';
    public function files_table()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(table1::class,'rid','rid');
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что `with('listfile')` возвращает все записи, а мне необходимо лишь одно поле `filename`. Каким можно запросить из `table2` только поле `filename`?

Comment: Что за таблицы? Это серверная реализация?

Comment: Прежняя тема с подробностями: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/743302/laravel-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/743474#743474

Comment: Эта тема к AngularJS не относится.

Comment: Перепутал. Это Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта вывода:

1) Если вам всегда нужно при обращении к реляции выводить только одно поле, тогда следует в самой реляции указать это поле:

```
public function listfile()
{
    return $this->hasMany(table2::class,'rid','rid')->select('filename', 'rid');
}
```

2) Если же это единичный случай, тогда в самой выборке нужно указать что именно выбрать хотим:

```
$data = table1::where('id', $id)
            ->with(['listfile' => function($query){
                $query->select('filename', 'rid');
            }])
            ->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->get()->toArray();
```

UPD. Так же вторым параметром нужно указать внешний ключ.

Comment: И в первом и во втором случае, у меня возвращается пустой массив listfile(). Не знаете, чем это может быть вызвано?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов значит реляция описана не правильно или данных нет, без select выводит данные?

Comment: Без select'a выводит все поля из второй таблицы

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов а в table2 есть такое поле filename?

Comment: Да. Этому полю в самой таблице никаких свойств задавать не надо?

Comment: Нет, забыл одну вещь, сейчас дополнил ответ, укажите в select ещё внешний ключ, в вашем случае из-за того что ключи одинаковые не знаю отработает или нет, но попробуйте.

Comment: Спасибо. Всё заработало =)